# How to detect if a string is variable In a code editor written QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit, qcompleter

I am writting a javascript code editor with QPlainTextEdit, and now I am workding on code completion with QCompleter.The question is I don't know which string is a variable in the plaintext.I firstly detect the variable according to the keysword，such as

```
var variable = "something";
class people{};
```

but it wouldn't work correctly when user paste serveral lines or delete multi lines, or user just delete single character of a exist "variable"

```
var variabl = "something";
```

obviously I don't want QCompleter to popup both "variable" and "variabl".
any solution ? thanks a lot.

[relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927289/how-to-update-qcompleters-model-dynamically?newreg=cf9b60de6b6047aea665a953ce8e6990)

Comment: var variable?? ??

Comment: It mostly depends on how you manage your data-model (the one of the QCompleter), please give more details about how it is done :) I don't understand your exact question, what's not working?

Comment: If you don't really need to reinvent... you know, [Scintilla](https://www.scintilla.org/) is nowadays the go-to implementation for such a purpose. There is even a QScintilla, but it's license is only GPL or commercial.